# Redis get list items and append prefix

Tags: list, redis, prefix

I have a list of Strings in redis -

```
LPUSH keys 1 2 3 4
```

And reading is pretty easy -

```
LRANGE keys 0 3

1) "4"
2) "3"
3) "2"
4) "1"
```

How can I read from list where each value has some specified string prepended to it? In above scenario I want my output as -

```
1) "Key:4"
2) "Key:3"
3) "Key:2"
4) "Key:1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use lua - https://redis.io/commands/eval

You can search for lua documentation and modify the code below according your needs.

Here is an example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> LPUSH keys 1 2 3 4
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379> LRANGE keys 0 3
1) "4"
2) "3"
3) "2"
4) "1"
127.0.0.1:6379> EVAL 'local res = {} local ttt=redis.call("LRANGE", "keys", "0", "10") for k, v in pairs(ttt) do table.insert(res, "Key:" .. v) end return res' 0
1) "Key:4"
2) "Key:3"
3) "Key:2"
4) "Key:1"
```